# How to open a url in new tab and switch focus to that tab?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is a way to open a new tab like with `window.open(url, '_blank')` and then switch to that tab immediately instead of staying in the current one. I tried using `.focus()` on returned window proxy but it does not work for some reason.

Thank you!

Comment: I hope not; that’d be pretty sketchy security-wise. I don’t think there’s anything standard.

Comment: I think it might be possible by simulating the click function. could you please share a code example in a snippet to understand you more?

Comment: What do you means by this `switch to that tab immediately instead of staying in the current one` . This working fine with me as you wrote:- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DSDmark/ycxs7kh9/1/). ever it works without `focus`.

Comment: @DSDmark Hm, you are right. I guess my problem is happening only when ctrl key is pressed `window.open` is happening. In this case, focus is not switching in your example as well

Comment: I think, Mr. @Eugene Tsakh. Your means is about to open whole new browser's tabs or  whole new browser's window in other words, not only tab.

Comment: @DSDmark no, I want a new tab not window...

Comment: Sorry, but on my that example [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DSDmark/ycxs7kh9/1/). It doesn't matter if you passed or not `CTRL` key, it's using `_blank` parameter. So, it pushes you on that new tab. Sorry but I think I'm not getting any idea. that what your question is all about.

Comment: @DSDmark try clicking on a button in your jsfiddle while pressing Ctrl key. It will open a new tab but won't switch to that tab

Comment: Okay, I get the idea, as I wrote `on my that example jsfiddle. It doesn't matter if you passed or not CTRL key, it's using _blank parameter. So, it pushes you on that new tab` it's apply in Firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: Bytheway, I'm using Firefox. Master @Eugene Tsakh in what sense you want that kind of opposite behaver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252049/discussion-between-dsdmark-and-eugene-tsakh).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is **not** possible - due to security concerns.